# Node.js socket hang up with http.get but not with request module

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, node-modules

I am performing some http calls in an AWS lambda. The number of calls are ~400 per minute. 
The calls are performed as in the following snippet

```
var req = http.get("https://www.google.com", res => {
    let body = '';
    res.on('data', chunk => {
        body += chunk;
    });
    res.on('end', chunk => {
        if (body.includes('html')) {
            console.log('Got back healthy response');
        } else {
            console.log('Got an unexpected response');
        }
    })
});
req.on('error', e => {
    console.log('Got an error response');
})
```

That is a simple https request. When the Lambda is invoked, it performs ~40 requests in a single execution.
My issue is that at the beginning, everything looks good and all the requests are performed correctly. After a while (that can be after ~30 min) calls start to degrade and I get back "socket hang up ECONNRESET" error.

I then tried using the request module and change the code with the following

```
const request = require('request');
request("https://www.google.com", function (error, response, body) {
  if (!error && response.statusCode == 200 && body.includes('html')) {
    console.log('Got back healthy response' );
  } else {
    console.log('Got an unexpected response');
    console.log('Error: ' + error);
    console.log('Response: ' + response);
    console.log('Body: ' + body);
  }
});
```

In this case, with the same number of requests within the same lambda, same setting I *never* get the ECONNRESET error.
I'm ok using the request module but I'm curious to know why this was happening with the default `http` implementation.
Is this caused by socket allocation that the `request` module handles in a more appropriate way?

I know similar questions have been asked already but I didn't find a good answer for my case.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really an answer but I cannot write comments.

The main difference I can see is the encoding. The default encoding in request is `utf8`, whereas in the http module it's `buffer`. Adding `res.setEncoding('utf8');` might be helpful. It might not be faster. In the line `body += chunk` you just implicitly convert a Buffer to a string so it should be the same.

If adding the `setEncoding` won't change anything then you might want to report an issue to the nodejs team because it's the same as the example in [http_http_get_url_options_callback](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_get_url_options_callback). They should fix it or change the example.